# UIWebView rotation overlapping buttons

Tags: ios, uiwebview, overlapping, screen-rotation

I have a `UIWebView` set up to reach three edges of a page in portrait mode. there is a small space at the top of the page where I put a few `UIButton`s and a `UITextField`.

On page load, I load a web page into the `UIWebView` and in portrait all looks as expected.  When I ask the simulator to rotate left or right to landscape, the buttons disappear or after playing a bit end up with the `UIWebView` behind the buttons that were at the top. I would like the `UIWebView` to stop just under the buttons as it did in portrait mode.

Any assistance would be appreciated.